# group_by a data frame by the grouping variables of another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the data frame `df`

```
df <- tibble(x = 1, y = 2) %>% group_by(x, y)
```

and I would like to group the data frame `df2` using the grouping variables of `df`.

This does not work:

```
df2 <- tibble(x = 3, y = 4) %>% group_by(groups(df))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_by_at` with `group_vars` (returns a character vector):

```
df2 <- tibble(x = 3, y = 4) %>% group_by_at(group_vars(df))

df2
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   x, y [1]
#      x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     4
```

Or if using `group_by` with `groups` which returns a list of symbols, you need `rlang::UQS` to splice the symbols as argument to `group_by`:

```
library(rlang)
df2 <- tibble(x = 3, y = 4) %>% group_by(UQS(groups(df)))
df2
# A tibble: 1 x 2
# Groups:   x, y [1]
#      x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3     4
```